# Android fullscreen activity without battery icon

Tags: android, view, android-fullscreen

I am developing an android application which contains a full screen activity but i am unable to hide default android battery , time etc. icons from the screen

For example :- [image: battery ,time etc icons are hidden within the view only]

I think this is something like android immersive full screen view

So can any one tell me how can i achieve this

Answer (score 4):

you can  do it in java file by

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

or in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

**With transparent notification bar** [read this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865621/transparent-status-bar-before-4-4-kitkat).

Comment: i want battery icon within view

Comment: i updated ans with the link to (i think) what you want

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature called Immersive FullScreen mode where all the UI elements other than your Activity are hidden. One can get those those back by swiping down.
Use the following code to achieve this :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```