# Setting status bar alpha or color to Android 4.0 (API 14)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, statusbar, navigationbar

I want to change color or just the alpha from my status bar and navigation bar, althought I know that to change the color normally you need to use android 5.0

somebody know a workaround or something to help me ?

Comment: maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865621/transparent-status-bar-before-4-4-kitkat

Comment: Thankys Tardo, but I want a solution for all kinds of mobile phone(Motorola, Samsung, Sony and ...);

Comment: This might help for other. Though its late. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469998/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-soft-keys-to-white-in-androidnavigation-buttons