# How do I change the color of soft keys to white in android(Navigation buttons)

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

I am making a basic launcher app where i needed my notification bar and status bar to be perfectly transparent. So i used below code.

```
Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Which does the trick but the color of the softkeys is not white as shown in figure below.

[image]

How do i make it white?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok finally solved it in lollipop. But i haven't tested in devices lower than lollipop.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Comment: And in Kotlin you would do:

        window.apply {
            addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            navigationBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        }

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be **impossible** for now. At least, on *non-rooted device*. These buttons show pre-defined images from ROM (part of part of `com.android.systemui`).

There's a discussion about theming softkeys on [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/themes-apps/softkeys-softkey-collection-t1413582)

The only real thing you can do is to choose between Light and Dark theme:

[image]

(Taken from https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-system-bars)

I won't be surprise if it changes in the future SDKs, though..

Comment: thanks for the reply. I got it solved in lollipop. But haven't tested in devices below lollipop.