# Transparent status bar not working with windowTranslucentNavigation="false"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-styles

I am developing an `Activity` where I need to make the navigation bar opaque, and the status bar transparent on devices running 5.0+ (API 21+). The styles I am using are below, along with an explanation of my problem.

**`AppTheme`** extends **`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`**

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/welbe_red_transparent</item>
```

**`FullscreenTheme`** extends **`AppTheme`**

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

This makes the app look like this

[image: android:windowTranslucentNavigation="true"]

If I remove the `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` style, or set it to `false` in `Fullscreen`, it fixes the navigation bar issue. The problem is the status bar turns completely white instead of staying transparent and displaying the content behind it.

[image: android:windowTranslucentNavigation="false"]

I have tried using `fitsSystemWindow="true"` in my layouts, but it didn't fix the issue. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to what you really want: navigation bar default, transparent status bar and your background behind the status bar. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to display. The background stops extending behind the status bar when I turn off `android:windowTranslucentNavigation`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`android:windowTranslucentNavigation` does one thing that `android:statusBarColor` doesn't do, which is requesting the `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` flags.

These are the ones that you need to request in order to draw behind the status bar.

Request them in the `onCreate` of your `Activity`:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Alternatively you can also simply set your apps theme background and that will also pop up behind your status bar.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856603/lollipop-draw-behind-statusbar-with-its-color-set-to-transparent/27923895#27923895).

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you. The docs say "adjust the window flags as required", but fail to mention which flags...

Comment: After lot of search and hours of efforts, I finally found the answer here. Many many thanks. As an additional note, we should remove `fitsSystemWindows` for this to work correct.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there's no proper way to set the color of the status bar on APIs lower than 19.

For API 19+ you can use a similar attribute to `windowTranslucentNavigation` only for the status bar:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

**Notes:**

- The reason you were getting a white status bar is because of

  ```
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
  ```
- There are [some hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049872/3249477) that work on specific manufacturer devices, but I wouldn't use them myself.

Comment: I understand how to accomplish this in a backwards compatible manner, I am using different styles on `19+` and `21+`. The background should be under the transparent status bar on `21+`, but the combination of settings I am using with AppCompat is breaking that feature somewhere. This answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @AustynMahoney "I need to make the navigation bar opaque, while keeping the status bar transparent on 5.0+" - done. "I also need this to work on minSdkVersion 14+" - won't work, 19+ only. What is your question then?

Comment: The question is still the same. Why does turning off `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` stop the background from fitting the system window fully (the reason why the status bar is white). I do not need the transparency to work on 14+ (I know its not possible), I just point out that the solution needs to use `AppCompat` themes/styles to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: @AustynMahoney well I did say that the statusBar is white because you're setting a transparent color, have you tried removing that?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I am trying to do here if you suggest removing the transparent color. "You can also draw behind the status bar yourself. For example, if you want to show the status bar transparently over a photo, with a subtle dark gradient to ensure the white status icons are visible. To do so, set the android:statusBarColor attribute to @android:color/transparent and adjust the window flags as required." - https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Comment: I am probably missing the noted, but never explained "adjust the window flags" part.

Comment: @AustynMahoney the link you posted, is for Material theme. It doesn't mean the AppCompat version. Your question still remains unclear. However using AppCompat with the attribute I provided (`windowTranslucentStatus`), does make the status bar translucent and content is drawn behind it. At least when running on API 21.

Comment: `android:windowTranslucentStatus` is a KitKat attribute, not AppCompat (I use it in my `19+` theme). It makes the status bar semi-translucent with a gradient for background protection. The new Material theme attributes let you have a completely transparent status bar. I apologize if this wasn't clear in my question. I have edited to make sure people know I am talking about this working on a 21+ Material Theme, which just happens to be AppCompat in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I struggle with this for over 3 hours. Wrap everything in a CoordinatorLayout it is the only one that seems to pay attention to the fitsSystemWindow="true" or  "false"

This is my main activity fragment

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_google_map"/>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar_transparent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_action_buttons"/>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is my toolbar layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fynd_logo_red"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

as you can see, my fragment layout makes the google map be drawn under the status bar.

I have an action bar where the company's logo goes.

And other ui buttons "layout_action_buttons"  also wrapped in a Coordinator layout , so the fitsSystemsWindows works.

Check it out.

[image]

Comment: Can You show how look compass button on google maps? Because for me is always under top statusbar, and I have problem with move google maps buttons

Comment: You can add padding to your google map. Use this,  mMap.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 10);  That's how you avoid your map components go under the bar.

Comment: @Peter also check the accepted answer too, having those flags on your activity will do the trick of drawing under the status bar, and even later change the color of the status bar.

Comment: I used defautl example project from Android studio 'Navigation dreawer activity'. I have 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout' and inside 'fragment' with google maps. I can't add padding to fragment. Any sugestions? :-)

Comment: @Peter check this out.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding

Comment: @PedroVarela Your screenshot is showing a weird shadow on top (that grey colored). How can you remove that ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To achieve this in any activity

1. Add the style:

> ```
>  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
>                 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
>                 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
>                 <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
>                 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
>                 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
>             </style>
> ```

2. Use CoordinatorLayout as root layout in XML
3. In oncreate() method, before setcontentview use

   window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

Comment: I want status bar only transparent but navigation should be default. in my case immersive mode full screen and transparent navigation ovelay on it

Answer (score 0):

For the latest android version R and backward compatibility, this works for me.

```
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars =false /* true for dark icon on StatusBar and false for white icon on StatusBar */
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(android.R.id.content)) { rootView, insets ->
    val navigationBarHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()).bottom
    rootView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, navigationBarHeight)
    insets
}
```

For Fragment, you can use `activity?.window...`