# Android: status bar not theme on transitiong to new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar

I have create a simple app with 2 activities. Main (launcher) activity is themed properly where `colorPrimaryDark` is applied to status bar.
But when I transition to new activity, everything seems normal except status bar. It somehow colored white. Any idea why this could be happening?

Running this on OnePlus One (Lollipop 5.0.2)

**Target api -> 16+**

[image]

**values/styles.xml**

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

**values-v21/styles.xml**

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/slide_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**layout/activity_settings.xml**

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#856"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289477/transparent-status-bar-not-working-with-windowtranslucentnavigation-false) will help you out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this affect the main launcher activity as well? PrimaryColorDark is automatically applied to main activity with these settings.

Comment: I believe it appears grey as you are setting the statusBarColor to transparent. Try removing that line entirely

Comment: If I change or remove above style, then my navigation drawer in the main activity loses one feature which draws the nav drawer under status bar. Like in this [image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-WmBBQQEJIKM/VWikAyy08sI/AAAAAAAABvc/1R36Txk83UI/s400/drawer.png)

So I kept the style as is and set changed the status bar color programmatically in the concerned activity:

getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.PrimaryDarkColor));

Comment: But it has to be in **values-v21/styles.xml**

Answer (score 1):

Change the api level to 11+, you can find it. change the Theme to DarkActionBar

Answer (score 1):

You might be not needing this anymore but I recently get this issue so maybe this will help others.

I fix it by creating new style in **values-v21/styles.xml** extending from the `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.SolidStatusBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
</style>
```

and use this as your new Activity theme in manifest. This way your changes don't have to interfere with activities that need to use translucent status bar like your Main activity.

I have no idea why is this happening though.

Answer (score 0):

In `values-v21/styles.xml`, change

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```