# Dynamically change status bar color without losing transparency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, drawerlayout, windowinsets

I know I can use `colorPrimary` to determine the color of `Toolbar`, and `colorPrimaryDark` to determine the color of Status bar.

I'm using the following theme

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Noteplus.Base.Brown" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0000</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

[image]

One of the interesting attribute is, when I slide out the navigation menu, the status bar becomes transparent automatically.

[image]

---

During run-time, sometime I would like to change the color of status bar.

```
setTitle("Recycler bin");
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#5694FF"));
```

It will looks as follow

[image]

**Unfortunately, calling `setStatusBarColor`, will also loss the transparency attribute of status bar, when we slide out the navigation menu.**

[image]

***May I know, how to change status bar color during run-time, without lossing its transparency attribute? For my case, after I changing the status bar to blue during run-time, when I slide out navigation drawer, I wish to see status bar transparency attribute being retained.***

---

### Update

I had tried

```
private void setStatusBarColor(int color) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(color);
    }
}
```

It doesn't help to provide transparency attribute when the navigation drawer slides out.

[image]

Comment: did you try this ? 
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#004D40")));

Comment: We have already did `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#5694FF"));`, as stated in my question.

Comment: YEah this is setBackgroundDrawable not setColor

Comment: We don't have `ActionBar` in our app. We use `Toolbar`. `getActionbar()` will return null.

Comment: my bad i confused the actionbar with statusbar, i added an answer, tho i dont have AndroidStudio to test right now but i think it will help

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594509/3283568

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `DrawerLayout`. That means, that instead of using [`Window#setStatusBarColor(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)) you should be using one of [`DrawerLayout#setStatusBarBackground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout#setstatusbarbackground) overloads.

The equivalent of your code is following:

```
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(0xFF5694FF);
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(colorDrawable);
```

I've applied minor changes to the template app that can be created with Android Studio wizard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem with transparency is not about the method you are using but its rather about the color itself!
You are using this `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#5694FF"));`

Try to use RGBA instead of RGB so make it transparent, should be something like this:

`getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#5694FF80"));`

Comment: That wouldn't help. https://i.imgur.com/9lmRAkg.png (We use `#7f757575`). We can use color without transparency in `colorPrimaryDark` (Which is `#ff0000`), yet retain status bar transparency attribute.

Comment: tell me if this will change anything: `Window win = getWindow();             win.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

and use it after chaning the color

Comment: in case this worked, (removed the status bar at all) then you can refer to this to find the correct flags you need to make it transparent or as android like to call to it TRANSLUCENT : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

```
private void changeStatusBarColor(String color){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
}
```

If you check here in stack overflow everyone before that line of code set the transparency of the status bar to solid with

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
```