# Android Completely transparent Status Bar?

Tags: android, statusbar

I've searched the *documentation* but only found this:
[Link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI). Which is used to make the bar ***translucent***? What I'm trying to do is to make the status bar ***completely transparent*** (as shown in the image below) and make it backwards compatible for APK<19:
[image]

My styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  <!-- Support library compatibility -->
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
  <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ThemeActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
  <item name="android:background"> @null </item>
  <!-- Support library compatibility -->
  <item name="background">@null</item>
  <item name="android:displayOptions"> showHome | useLogo</item>
  <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>

  </style>

</resources>
```

What I was able to do:

[image]

Comment: Latest from official sources: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/translucent-systembars-the-right-way-across-api-levels-and-themes-6d7ddda21396

Comment: [For newer APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451704/transparent-status-bar-with-visible-navigation-bar/68492550#68492550)

Answer (score 489, accepted):

All you need to do is set these properties in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Your activity / container layout you wish to have a transparent status bar needs this property set:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

It is generally not possible to perform this for sure on pre-kitkat, looks like you can do it [but some strange code makes it so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865621/transparent-status-bar-before-4-4-kitkat).

EDIT: I would recommend this lib: https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint for lots of pre-lollipop status bar color control.

Well after much deliberation I've learned that the answer to totally disabling the translucency or any color placed on the status bar and navigation bar for lollipop is to set this flag on the window:

```
// In Activity's onCreate() for instance
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

No other theme-ing is necessary, it produces something like this:

[image]

Comment: I used the code and then added an image as background and then added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my activity_main.xml. The system bars are translucent and not transparent.

Comment: Nearly there! Do you want to remove the status bar entirely (icons etc. too)? Or set that semi-opaque black to a transparent color? I've done some digging and from what I can see there's actually no obvious way to totally remove the color but keep the icons on pre-lollipop. Lollipop has a statusBarColor theme item.

Comment: 2nd: make the _semi-opaque_ to _transparent_. And of course it should only do this if it's Lollipop otherwise it should just be _semi-opaque_.

Comment: Well I believe all you need in that case then is to add `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` to your theme :)

Comment: Hmm, we're getting close :D Try setting this in the theme as well `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>` I believe it's actually what tells android to use the statusBarColor property you set (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds)

Comment: Yes we are, thank you for your patience, I'm on almost on a tilt since I've been trying to do this for the past few hours xD. The code above doesn't work however I set the `android:windowTranslucentStatus` to false and it made the status bar transparent. Now I did the same thing with navigaton bar and added `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` but it makes both bars grey. UGH!

Comment: To make "adjustPan" work use 
`w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);`
instead

Comment: NOTE: using the FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag will also put your layout under the virtual nav bar at the bottom.  In general, you don't want to do this...so ditto what other folks have said :-(

Comment: For anyone who android:fitsSystemWindows="true" wasn't sufficient:
https://proandroiddev.com/draw-under-status-bar-like-a-pro-db38cfff2870

Comment: Here's a [short and sweet solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426061/12980866) to this problem

Comment: @ArdaKara with `w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);` adjustPan works but "fullscreen" does not (content starts after status bar)

Answer (score 41):

**You Can Use Below Code To Make Status Bar Transparent.**
**See Images With red highlight which helps you to identify use of Below code**

[image: 1]]

**Kotlin code snippet for your android app**

**Step:1** Write down code in On create Method

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true)
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}
```

**Step2:** You Need  SetWindowFlag method which describe in Below code.

```
private fun setWindowFlag(bits: Int, on: Boolean) {
    val win = window
    val winParams = win.attributes
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags = winParams.flags or bits
    } else {
        winParams.flags = winParams.flags and bits.inv()
    }
    win.attributes = winParams
}
```

**Java code snippet for your android app:**

**Step1:** Main Activity Code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

**Step2:** SetWindowFlag Method

```
public static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
    Window win = activity.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

Comment: I also added this: <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: How about just using `Window#addFlags` and / or `Window#clearFlags`?

Answer (score 40):

Just add this line of code to your main java file:

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
);
```

Comment: This affects the navigation bar too.

Comment: This breaks SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN and SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE so scrolling is not possible

Comment: this is not working for android one plus!

Answer (score 30):

Works for Android KitKat and above (For those who want to transparent the status bar and don't manipulate the NavigationBar, because all of these answers will transparent the NavigationBar too!)

The easiest way to achieve it:

Put these 3 lines of code in the `styles.xml (v19)` -> if you don't know how to have this (v19), just write them in your default `styles.xml` and then use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to automatically create it:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>
```

And now, go to your `MainActivity` Class and put this Method out of onCreate in the class:

```
public static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {

    Window win = activity.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

Then put this code in the `onCreate` method of the Activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    //make fully Android Transparent Status bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

That's it!

Comment: As my experience in React Native... 
The codes above is conflict with showing the keyboard (adjustResize).
So, I just make little changes:
```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        }
```
and in Component
```
<StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent" />
```
and in AppManisfes - MainActivity
```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and the rest codes are same.

fyi:
```
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

thank you @parsa dadras

Comment: If you are putting code in onCreate() method then no need to change style. It will work.

Answer (score 18):

**Completely Transparent StatusBar and NavigationBar**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    transparentStatusAndNavigation();
}


private void transparentStatusAndNavigation() {
    //make full transparent statusBar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        );
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        setWindowFlag(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, false);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}

private void setWindowFlag(final int bits, boolean on) {
    Window win = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    } else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I just found it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge)

Because it's already pass 6 years, and the default minSDKAPI is 21 (Lollipop) *CMIIW. Here is my way to conclude transparent status bar and not overlapping with navigation button:

```kotlin
fun setStatusBarTransparent(activity: Activity, view: View) {
    activity.apply {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { root, windowInset ->
            val inset = windowInset.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            root.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                leftMargin = inset.left
                bottomMargin = inset.bottom
                rightMargin = inset.right
                topMargin = 0
            }
            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
        }
    }
}
```

To show the status bar again just need a few change:

```kotlin
fun setStatusBarShown(activity: Activity, view: View) {
    activity.apply {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { root, windowInset ->
            val inset = windowInset.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            val inset1 = windowInset.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
            root.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                leftMargin = inset.left
                bottomMargin = inset.bottom
                topMargin = inset1.top
                rightMargin = inset.right
            }
            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
        }
    }
}
```

I put that function inside `Object` class called `UiUtils` so when I call that function in my activity (I using View Binding too). It'll look like this:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...
    UiUtils.setStatusBarTransparent(this, bind.root)
    ...
}
```

Hope my answer can help you guys :)

Comment: Now it works but when I again want to use `setStatusBarTransparent` it is not working. I have to set `topMargin = 0` in `updateLayoutParams`. Seems to be working properly. Thank You so much, You saved me!

Comment: Yeah, if you are manage to transparent the status again, set the inset from the system bars again

Comment: what is the difference between inset and inset1 ? It looks the same.

Comment: inset1 for taking the inset from the status bar. In the statusBarShown function is for showing the status bar again. That's why we need to take inset from the status bar.

Answer (score 11):

To draw your layout under statusbar:

values/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

values-v21/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Use CoordinatorLayout/DrawerLayout which already take care of the fitsSystemWindows parameter or create your own layout to like this:

```
public class FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout extends ConstraintLayout {

    private Drawable mStatusBarBackground;
    private boolean mDrawStatusBarBackground;

    private WindowInsetsCompat mLastInsets;

    private Map<View, int[]> childsMargins = new HashMap<>();

    public FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(this)) {
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this, new android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                @Override
                public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                    FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout layout = (FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout) view;
                    layout.setChildInsets(insets, insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() > 0);
                    return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
                }
            });
            setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.colorPrimaryDark});
            try {
                mStatusBarBackground = typedArray.getDrawable(0);
            } finally {
                typedArray.recycle();
            }
        } else {
            mStatusBarBackground = null;
        }
    }

    public void setChildInsets(WindowInsetsCompat insets, boolean draw) {
        mLastInsets = insets;
        mDrawStatusBarBackground = draw;
        setWillNotDraw(!draw && getBackground() == null);

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(this)) {
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

                    if (ViewCompat.getFitsSystemWindows(child)) {
                        ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(child, insets);
                    } else {
                        int[] childMargins = childsMargins.get(child);
                        if (childMargins == null) {
                            childMargins = new int[]{layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin, layoutParams.rightMargin, layoutParams.bottomMargin};
                            childsMargins.put(child, childMargins);
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.leftToLeft == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = childMargins[0] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft();
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.topToTop == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.topMargin = childMargins[1] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.rightToRight == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.rightMargin = childMargins[2] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetRight();
                        }
                        if (layoutParams.bottomToBottom == LayoutParams.PARENT_ID) {
                            layoutParams.bottomMargin = childMargins[3] + insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        requestLayout();
    }

    public void setStatusBarBackground(Drawable bg) {
        mStatusBarBackground = bg;
        invalidate();
    }

    public Drawable getStatusBarBackgroundDrawable() {
        return mStatusBarBackground;
    }

    public void setStatusBarBackground(int resId) {
        mStatusBarBackground = resId != 0 ? ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), resId) : null;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setStatusBarBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        mStatusBarBackground = new ColorDrawable(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mDrawStatusBarBackground && mStatusBarBackground != null) {
            int inset = mLastInsets != null ? mLastInsets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() : 0;
            if (inset > 0) {
                mStatusBarBackground.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), inset);
                mStatusBarBackground.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/toolbar_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Content"
            android:textSize="48sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FitsSystemWindowConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's not a transparent status bar, that's a translucent status bar

Answer (score 11):

Simple and crisp and works with almost all use cases (for API level 16 and above):

1. Use the following tag in your app theme to make the status bar transparent:

   `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`
2. And then use this code in your activity's onCreate method.

   ```
   View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
   decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
   ```

That's all you need to do ;)

You can learn more from the [developer documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status#behind) I'd also recommend reading [this](https://proandroiddev.com/draw-under-status-bar-like-a-pro-db38cfff2870) blog post.

**KOTLIN CODE**:

```
    val decorView = window.decorView
    decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

Check my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63460431/12980866)

Comment: This breaks SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE and SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN

Comment: 'SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN are deprecated

Answer (score 11):

For API > 23 with Day/Night support you can use the extension below. Important part to understand is that `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` uses padding to move within insets (like you would with a Toolbar). Therefore it does not make sense to place it at your root layout (except DrawerLayout, CoordinatorLayout, ... these use their own implementation).

[image]

```xml
<style name="Theme.YourApp.DayNight" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">@bool/isDayMode</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        ...
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

```kotlin
fun Activity.transparentStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    } else {
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```kotlin
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        transparentStatusBar()
    }
}
```

Check these slides by Chris Banes: [Becoming a master window fitter](https://chris.banes.dev/becoming-a-master-window-fitter-lon/)

**Edit:** If you have problems with content floating behind your navigation bar, use

```kotlin
// using Insetter
binding.yourViewHere.applySystemWindowInsetsToPadding(bottom = true)
```

Comment: I think you can also use the support library WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

Comment: wow, thanks after so many months of searching internet. But know that it's only the kotlin code that works for it . That means fitsSystemWindows wasn't working at all

Answer (score 10):

Here is a extension in kotlin that do the trick:

```
fun Activity.setTransparentStatusBar() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**THERE ARE THREE STEPS:**

**1)** Just use this code segment into your OnCreate method

```
  // FullScreen
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

If you’re working on Fragment, you should put this code segment in your activity’s OnCreate method.

**2)** Be sure to also set the transparency in /res/values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Or you can set the transparency programmatically:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

**3)** In anyway you should add the code segment in styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

**NOTE:** This method just works on API 21 and above.

Comment: the java works!

Answer (score 8):

**This is a simple way I found it after a lot of searches.**

> **Step 1**

in your theme put this item

```
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

> **Step 2**

In main Activity

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

**Very Important if u used BottomNavigationBar**

in some devices, with API 30+ u will find system navigation bar overlap with bottom navigation bar if used it in your application.

this is solving for this problem.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
        // Root ViewGroup of my activity
        val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(root) { view, windowInsets ->

            val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

            // Apply the insets as a margin to the view. Here the system is setting
            // only the bottom, left, and right dimensions, but apply whichever insets are
            // appropriate to your layout. You can also update the view padding
            // if that's more appropriate.

            view.layoutParams =  (view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
                leftMargin = insets.left
                bottomMargin = insets.bottom
                rightMargin = insets.right
            }

            // Return CONSUMED if you don't want want the window insets to keep being
            // passed down to descendant views.
            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in your top layout

Comment: this affects Navigation bar too

Answer (score 7):

I found fiddling with styles.xml and activity to be too cumbersome hence created a common utility method which has below options set

Java

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Kotlin DSL

```
activity.window.apply {
    clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}
```

And that's all it took to achieve transparent status bar. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using this code in your XML, you will be able to see time bar in your activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
private static void setStatusBarTransparent(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        activity.getWindow(). setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } else {
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

it just removes the statusBar color!

```
window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
window?.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

[image]

It worked for me, hope it works for you too

Answer (score 2):

To achieve completely transparent status bar:
First make the custom theme in themes.xml as

```
<style name="Theme.QuiloThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Java:

```
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Kotlin :

```
activity.window.apply {
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All one need is to go into `MainActivity.java`

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window g = getWindow();
        g.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, i dont call at all "onCreate" (its a react native app and this can be fixes also by using the react-native StatusBar component)  one can also use this:

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While all the answers above circulate around the same fundamental idea and you can get it to work with simple layouts using one of the examples above. However I wanted to change the color of the background while using sliding 'full screen' (tab bar aside) fragment navigation and maintain regular navigation, tab and action bars.

After reading carefully [an article by Anton Hadutski](https://proandroiddev.com/draw-under-status-bar-like-a-pro-db38cfff2870) I had better understanding what is going on.

I have `DrawerLayout` with `ConstraintLayout` (i.e. container) which has `Toolbar`, include for the main fragment and `BottomNavigationView`.

Setting `DrawerLayout` having `fitsSystemWindows` to true isn't sufficient, you need to set both `DrawerLayout` and `ConstraintLayout`. Assuming transparent status bar, the status bar color is now the same as the background color of `ConstraintLayout`.

However, the included fragment has still the status bar inset, so animating another 'full screen' fragment on top of with doesn't change the color of the status bar.

A bit of code from the referred article into `Activity`'s `onCreate`:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.container)) { view, insets ->
        insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(
                insets.systemWindowInsetLeft,
                0,
                insets.systemWindowInsetRight,
                insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
        )
    }
```

And all is good, except now the `Toolbar` doesn't address the status bar height. Some more referring to the article and we have a fully working solution:

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.my_toolbar)
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.container)) { view, insets ->
        val params = toolbar.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        params.topMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetTop
        toolbar.layoutParams = params
        insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(
                insets.systemWindowInsetLeft,
                0,
                insets.systemWindowInsetRight,
                insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
        )
    }
```

The main_activity.xml (please note that marginTop in `Toolbar` is for preview purposes, it will be replaced by the code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/container"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp" 
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            ...>
            ...
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
        ...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    ...
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Kotlin Extension:

```
fun Activity.transparentStatusBar() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT

    } else
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is intended for those who want to have a completely transparent **StatusBar** and have the **NavigationBar** unaffected. Incredibly this sounds so simple that it has caused a headache to more than one, including me.

This is the final result I'm talking about

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A9lx.png)

We are going to need only two functions, that I recommend to invoke in the OnCreate of our Activity, the first one is *setStatusBar()*, that is in charge of making transparent to the same one.

```
private fun setStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    window.apply {
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        } else {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        }
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
}
```

The second one, *setMargins()* is in charge of setting the margins corresponding to the views that are restricted with the top, since otherwise, these views would be seen below the StatusBar.

```
private fun setMargins() {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
        findViewById(R.id.your_parent_view)
    ) { _, insets ->
        val view = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.your_child_view)
        val params = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        params.setMargins(
            0,
            insets.systemWindowInsetTop,
            0,
            0
        )
        view.layoutParams = params
        insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
    }
}
```

The final code would look like:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout))
        setStatusBar()
        setMargins()
}

private fun setStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    window.apply {
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        } else {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        }
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
}

private fun setMargins() {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
        findViewById(R.id.your_parent_view)
    ) { _, insets ->
        val view = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.your_child_view)
        val params = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        params.setMargins(
            0,
            insets.systemWindowInsetTop,
            0,
            0
        )
        view.layoutParams = params
        insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
    }
}
```

You can find a more detailed explanation of all this in the following [Post](https://proandroiddev.com/android-full-screen-ui-with-transparent-status-bar-ef52f3adde63)

I also leave a [Test Project](https://github.com/Dvik/TransparentStatusBar) where these concepts are working.

Answer (score 1):

For the last update from google. This is my code. This will transparent for statusbar and navigationbar:
Change your theme to this:

```
 <style name="Theme.Pink" 
 parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/pink_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/pink_dark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/pink_light</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/pink_primary</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 //transparent statusbar
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
//transparent navigationbar
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item> 
 </style>
```

Then in layout (file xml): Add 2 properties point_top and point_bottom to determine the position of the margin value of other components of the app:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/point_top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/point_bottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
   
       <.....>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in baseActivity or yourActivity: add this code in onCreate:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = setLayout()
    //set inset for view
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { _, insets ->
        val paramsTop =
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.point_top).layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams
        paramsTop.setMargins(0, insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).top, 0, 0)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.point_top).layoutParams = paramsTop
        val paramsBottom =
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.point_bottom).layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams
        paramsBottom.setMargins(0, 0, 0, insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).bottom)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.point_bottom).layoutParams = paramsBottom
        insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()

    }

    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Hope this to help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

just call this function this works in new/old android apis:

```
private fun changeScreenSystemUiController(isFullScreen: Boolean) {
    window?.also {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it, !isFullScreen)
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(it, it.decorView).apply {
            systemBarsBehavior =
                if (isFullScreen)
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                else
                    WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_TOUCH
            if (isFullScreen)
                hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            else
                show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            it.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
                if (isFullScreen)
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
                else
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_DEFAULT
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting in **2024**, I attempted to eliminated those deprecation methods to make the StatusBar completely transparent, and I reached to a solution. It's quite simple. Follow below:

- -> In Activity theme, choose a NoActionBar theme, like **Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar**.
- -> After that, configure some properties of this theme according to the code below:

  ```
  <style name="NoToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">?attr/isLightTheme</item> 
  </style>
  ```

  Where:

  - **android:statusBarColor** is the color of StatusBar and must have a different value for **Light** and **Dark**, example: **(Light: #FFFBFF, Dark: #030303)**
  - **android:windowTranslucentStatus** is a property related to Translucent StatusBar and must be **false**.
  - **android:windowLightStatusBar** paints elements from the StatusBar correctly. Adding **?attr/isLightTheme**, it's a variable that automatically sets true if it's Light theme, or false, if it's Dark.
- -> After that, just add this conditional according to the SDK version in **onCreate** of your activity.

  ```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
       window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
    } else {
       window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` only work on v21. We can set it in theme xml or in parent layout like `LinearLayout` or in `CoordinateLayout` . 
For below v21, We could not add this flag.
Please create different values folder with  different  `style.xml` file  as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
            <!--<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>-->
```

Dont use `windowLightStatusBar` use instead `statusBarColor = @android:color/transparent`

Answer (score 0):

add these lines into your Activity before the setContentView()

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

add these 2 lines into your AppTheme

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

and last thing your minSdkVersion must b 19

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

Comment: bad solution if user only want to make for some specific activity

Answer (score 0):

in my case as I've a bottom tool bar I had a problem when testing the previous solutions, the android system buttons are covered with my bottom menu
my solution is to add within the activity:

> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
> ```
>     // force full screen mode
>     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
>             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
>
>
>     setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_container);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN); 
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Include this layout in your main layout.

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlBackImageLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/main_background2">  //add your color here

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarIcon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/nav_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_semibold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="test Data" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Note: You can replace SDP and SSP with dp and sp respectively.**

Answer (score 0):

This should work

// In Activity's onCreate() for instance

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will make your status bar along with the navigation bar transparent (note that this will make your layout a full screen layout like the layouts used in games):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables sticky immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.
    // Or for regular immersive mode replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

To learn more, visit [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) link.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a fully transparent status bar:

```
package com.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    public static void setWindowFlag(Activity activity, final int bits, boolean on) {
        Window win = activity.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Native, other posts don't work. React has its own way to deal with it.

`<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />` from `react-native` is the way to go, thx to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427466/how-to-make-statusbar-transparent) this will override android setting in App.

However, 2 things to know:

1. If you are using `<Header />` component from `react-native-elements`, it already have `<StatusBar />` included, using its `statusBarProps` instead.
2. If you are using WIX react-native-navigation, they have a separate way to dealing with the status bar, refer to [this](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/style-statusBar/) and [this](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/style-options/). They said it is incompatible with React Native's , however, looks like they work well together for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is only for API Level >= 21. It works for me.
Here is my code (Kotlin)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).systemUiVisibility =
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer while I investigating this library:
https://github.com/laobie/StatusBarUtil

so you need to add following codes to your activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
} else {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most elegant solution in 2022:

```
private fun hideStatusBar() {
    val windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView) ?: return
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
}
```