# Android Studio: How to create a translucent status bar within collapsingtoolbarlayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-statusbar

I am a beginner and I don't know how to put a dark translucent statusbar when the collapsingtoolbarlayout is open? Any hint or idea? Thanks !!

[image]

The resulted what I wanted should be like this.....
[image]

## MainActivity.java

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.thesis.heppie.activity.MainActivity">



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="15dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/header_main"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


         </RelativeLayout>

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



      </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/grey_bg"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >


      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>
      </LinearLayout>



      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB2"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB1"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>






 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar/29311321#29311321).

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

It also makes transparent the navigation bar. Hope it helps :)