# How to make status bar transparent when using CoordinatorLayout in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-statusbar

I hava a problem, when i using CoordinatorLayout which contain an imageview
in fragment,i can't make the status bar transparent and draw the imageview under the status bar(in activity it's ok).

To illustration the problem,i take [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) for an example.

There's a CheeseDetailActivity in cheesesquare shows some content like this(which effect it's i want):

[image: in activity] 
As we know,it easy to make this effect in activity,i pick up the key code:

- styles.xml(v21)

  < resources>

  < style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
      < item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true
      < item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent
  < /style >

< /resources>

- activity_detail.xml

  ```
  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
      app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/backdrop"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  ```

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingTop="24dp">

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

          <LinearLayout
              style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Info"
                  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

          </LinearLayout>

      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

          <LinearLayout
              style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Friends"
                  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

          </LinearLayout>

      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

          <LinearLayout
              style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="Related"
                  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

              <TextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

          </LinearLayout>

      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

- the problem

Now,for some reason ,i want to show the same content in fragment but not in activity.I try to modify the code in cheesesquare .I just add a fragment and the style.xml and layout.xml is almost the same.Then the problem exist:

[image]

the status bar look look different! I confirm the style and layout is the same.So my question is what makes different?How can i make the status bar transparent?

**EDIT:**

- the xmls after modify

**activity_main.xml(modified)**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!--<include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager"/>-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        class="com.support.android.designlibdemo.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>
```

**fragment_main.xml(added)**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.support.android.designlibdemo.MainFragment">

<include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager"/>
```

**include_list_viewpager.xml(no modify)**

**style.xml(no modify)**

**activity_cheese_detail.xml(deleted)**

**fragment_cheese_detail.xml(added,just copy the source activity_cheese_detail.xml)**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                             tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Please show the xmls after added the fragment.

Comment: ok, the question is edited.

Answer (score 7):

You can this in *Java* code

```
protected void makeTransperantStatusBar(boolean isTransperant) {
    if (isTransperant) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    } else {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
}
```

if you want complete transperent you should do following

add these lines in your theme

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

set this flag in your co-ordinator layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

at last add these lines in `onCreate` method of `Activity`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```

reference [solution taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/5235032)

Answer (score 1):

Remove or change to a CoordinatorLayout type (with fitSystemWindows) the FrameLayout parent of a CoordinatorLayout child.

Comment: FrameLayout doesnt dispatch the insets informations to its childs.  Use CoordinatorLayout type instead as parent of a nested CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use kitkat+ android to have this option.

Add this code to your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```