# Color behind status bar but keep transparency

Tags: android, toolbar

so I'm trying to have a translucent statusbar and navbar, where the status bar gets it's color from the toolbar and the navbar gets its color from the content being display underneat it.

Like this:

[image]

This however was made possible with some hackery:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/alt_grad"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            ...
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            ...
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    ...

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Notice the transparent toolbar and tablayout with the 300dp height view not respecting fitSystemWindows painting under then with the gradient.

Without this type of hackery this is as far as I can get to:

[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/alt_grad"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            ...
            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            ...
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        ...
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any ideas on how i can manage to do this? Thanks!

Comment: can you post your alt_grad.xml here?

Comment: While you can change the action bar, I don't think you can change the status bar, but I'd just like to point out before you spend a long time on this, that it breaks [Google Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/) which vastly reduces the chances of getting featured etc.

Comment: Use same color for status bar as for toolbar. Dont use translucent

Comment: see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar

Comment: <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#f00"
        android:endColor="#0f0"
        android:angle="0"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"/>
</shape>