# Android: Any simple way to get a completely transparent status bar?

Tags: android, statusbar

This question has been asked several times -- and answered, but the answers don't seem to "add up".

Yes, one can simply set android:windowTranslucentStatus to true and set the WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag.  (See [Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)) That produces a completely transparent status bar (in recent Android releases).  That's great!

The issue is that this then results in the soft navigation bar being drawn over the lower contents (e.g. controls) within one's activity.  I've tried resolving this with fitSystemWindows, but currently am clearly getting something wrong.  Overall, it seems quite wrong that one has to get into *any* of this mess just to get a completely transparent vs. a translucent status bar!