# App name is show in Transparent Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Actually i am creating transparent overlay Application but when the the activity starts the application name is showing in the middle of screen rest everything is working fine...
So how can i remove the application name

Check Screnshot : the Screenhot text is the Application Name
[image: Screenshot]

Manifest file Code :

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.ServiceManagement"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"></activity>
```

Style sheet :

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Comment: This behaviour may come from toolbar. try `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` as `<activity>` theme

Comment: i got this  java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: now its working fine, but the statusBar Color is showing

Comment: Annother maybe... I don't have tested myself what you want to achive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/4681367

Comment: Try giving the label as "" in Manifest.

Answer (score 2):

If your transparent activity is an `AppCompatActivity`, then use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` as its parent theme. Directly adding these attributes to your activity's theme will also work.

```
<!-- no 'android:' prefix -->    
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```