# How to change statusBar background and icons color on Android

Tags: java, android, android-styles

In my application I want set **transparent** background to `statusBar` and set **white** color to `statusBar` **icons**.

I write below codes and set **transparent** background to `statusBar` and `navigationBar` .

But I want just set **transparent** background to `statusBar` (**not navigationBar**) and change `statusBar` icons color **from black to white**.

**Style codes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary21</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Java codes:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

**And set this flag to rootLayout :** `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

my codes result is :

How can I fix it? please help me
[image]

Comment: Go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar

Comment: @AkshayKatariya,  please see my codes, I write my code with your link. but show me above result

Comment: @AkshayKatariya, above above your link set transparent for navigationBar. I want set transparent just statusBar

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ransparent_color_resource));
    }
```

Hope this helps.