# Place webview behind status bar, tool bar and navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I'd like to place the `webview` behind the status bar, tool bar and navigation bar as shown in the picture from whatsapp

[image]

This is the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eupdates.eupdates.Pictures2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Basicly I need to place the webview behind the bars

Comment: This is duplicate Question :
Please refer this link :


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar

Answer (score 0):

From api 19 you can use these in your theme of that activity:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

and this line in the root of the layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

                <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/webview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    android:background="#5b5b5b5b"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ACTIVIY CODE**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView wb;

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        wb = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wb.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod?tab=profile");

    }


}
```

**STYLE.XML**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#5b5b5b5b</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]