# How to Have a Transparent Status Bar but Leave Navigation Bar Opaque?

Tags: android, styles, transparency, statusbar, navigationbar

I want to have a transparent status bar on my app (so the background goes behind it) but I want the navigation bar at the bottom to stay black.

I can make both transparent by setting `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

I can make the top translucent (partially transparent) by setting `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

However, I can't make the top completely transparent without making the bottom transparent too. Using `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` or similar doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to make a fully transparent status bar without affecting the navigation bar?

Comment: I answered this question in another post and it *works perfectly* ( **Making the StatusBar Transparent while NavigationBar Stay Stable** ) : [Android Completely transparent Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299648/6842344)

Answer (score 18):

To independently control the transluscency of the status and navigation bars on KitKat, you can simply use the window manager flags `FLAG_TRANSLUSCENT_STATUS` and `FLAG_TRANSLUSCENT_NAVIGATION` in the `onCreate()` method of your activity.  However, on KitKat the system may draw a semi-opaque gradient scrim drawable over the status bar.  This appears to be device-specific: on my KitKat device it's fully transparent, but on Android Studio emulator it shows a scrim.

On Lolliop or later you can instead set the status bar colour using the `Window#setStatusBarColor(int)` method together with the `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` window manager flag.  Note that you **clear** the `FLAG_TRANSLUSCENT_STATUS` flag in this case.  If you want the colour to be transparent, that implies that your application supports full screen mode and sets the system UI visibility, so it's down to your app to manage the status bar background colour.

Putting it all together would look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Window window = getWindow();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(0x00000000);  // transparent
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
        window.addFlags(flags);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Example of layout used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff00ff00"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Example screenshots.

Lollipop:

[image: Lollipop+]

KitKat:

[image: Kitkat]

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code (I'm definitely running more than Android KitKat) but it doesn't create a _transparent_ status or nav, only a translucent one (so the status/nav bar has a darker overlay than the background underneath). It's as though its color setting is alpha 0.5. Seeing this, I tried setting its color in style to alpha 0 and to transparent, but neither fix it. I know you said, "Transluscent in this case actually means fully transparent: there is no colour or alpha channel applied to either" but I can't get it to be anything other than just translucent. Do you know why?

Comment: I also tried the Window#setNavigationBarColor(TransparentColor)  after setting the flag, but it didn't seem to have any effect on its translucency  (forgot to mention that above).

Comment: You are quite right.  On some devices (or probably most devices!) it does show a semi-opaque scrim over the status bar background.  It just happens that on my KitKat device (Asus Transformer TF701T) it is fully transparent.  I have updated the answer to show a fully transparent status bar on Lollipop+ using a full-screen layout and controlling the system UI visibility.  I haven't yet found a way of reliably having the status bar fully transparent on KitKat though.

Comment: Finally!! Something that works! Thanks OP and AGDownie.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from API level 30, most of window flags are deprecated,

Using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` Will make the activity overlaps with the navigation bar, also makes it transparent.

So, instead to make this work on API level 30, you can use `setDecorFitsSystemWindows()`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in 21..29) { 
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
        SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
}

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
    // Setting status bar color as not working with XML attribute
    window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    // Making status bar overlaps with the activity
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
}
```

And keep the below in the styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
```

**UPDATE**

If you faced that the bottom part of layout obscured by the bottom navigation; please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68451704/transparent-status-bar-with-visible-navigation-bar#68492550) fore more in detail.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out :D

```
private void setTransparentStatusBarOnly(Activity activity) {
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    // this lines ensure only the status-bar to become transparent without affecting the nav-bar
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: How to, on the contrary, show status, but make the navigation bar transparent?

Comment: You are genius sir

Answer (score 0):

I am reposting the correct answer  that worked for me in kotlin :-

Paste code given below before `setContentView` in your activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.setStatusBarColor(0x00000000) // transparent
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        val flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
        window.addFlags(flags)
    }
```

In your style paste both the lines given below in the main theme:-

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
```

In your Layout just paste `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in Your parent Layout and then paste the same `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your child layout which u want to show in the background of the status bar like this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/dish_details_rootLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".bottomnav.menu.dishdetail.DishDetail"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/dish_details_appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/dish_details_collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/colorTransparentwhite"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dish_details_dish_imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dish_details_nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dish_details_horizontalGuideline1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dish_details_dishName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="Food Name"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dish_details_dishPrice"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="Rs. 200"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dish_details_dishRatingtxt"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                            android:text="4.5"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="24sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rating_star"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dish_details_dishDespricption"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="Food Description"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/dish_detail_add_to_cartbtn"
android:text="Add to Cart"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/soothingred_btn_bg"
/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my answer help someone.

```
fun setTransparentStatusBar(activity: Activity) {
            activity?.let {
                it.window?.let {
                    it.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
                    it.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
                    it.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                    it.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                }
            }
        }
```