# How to put pagertitlestrip in the center top

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

I am trying to update my app and wanted to make the toolbar look like the black player[image: this type of]. As of now i am able to set the search and navigation but how to put the pager title strip in the middle as inside viewpager i cannot use gravity i tried the margin and padding not working at all.
this is my xml

```
   <com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <me.alexrs.fontpagertitlestrip.lib.FontPagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/titlestrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:background="@color/material_fragment_top"

        app:fontFamily="@font/font"

        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar" />
```

how i can put the pagertitlestrip in the middle

[image: It is overlaping] So I want to put the padding but not able to do it at all

Comment: Google "TabLayout with ViewPager"

Comment: @Xenolion sir i am already using these but you can see the result if i add navigation or search it will not come in the same line as the pagertitle strip

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to change StatusBarColor.

try `setStatusBarColor(int)`and set colour of your toolbar or you can make it transparent
All you need to do is set these properties in your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Your activity / container layout you wish to have a transparent status bar needs this property set:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

but since you never specified API you're using I refer you to different question, you should find the answer.

[How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

[Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)

Comment: Thx for trying bro but i am not trying to make it transparent try to read the question i am already getting what you posted