# Fixed Status bar and hidden Navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar

Is it possible to hide the navbar without hiding the status bar?

I've tried this in my styles's xml

```
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and I hide de navbar like this in the activity

```
  val decorView = window.decorView
        val uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
```

Thank you!!

**Edit:**

```
   fun hideNavigationStatusBar(activity: Activity) {
        activity.window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
        val decorView = activity.window.decorView
        val uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
    }

    fun translucidNavigationBar(activity: Activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            val w = activity.window
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
        }
    }
```

I can hide status and navigation bar with the first method and keep the status with a translucent navigation with the second, but still I can't reach to keep the status and completely hide the navigation bar.

Comment: please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47977279/4748607)

Comment: I wanted to solve it without using a library, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is in two parts, removing the navbar and then making the status bar transparent.

**1 - Removing the navbar**

To remove the navbar, create a new style on the styles.xml file under the values folder that inherits from Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdMLQ.png]

Then on the manifest.xml file change the theme of the Activity to your custom style.

[image: Edited manifest]

With this the navbar will be removed, but the status bar will still be grayed out.

**2 - Making the status bar transparent**

You can follow this tutorial to make the status bar transparent: [Transparent Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)

Or just add the following to the onCreate method of your Activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
Window w = getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

[image]

With this you can expect an App style similar to the one in the next picture:

[image]

**3 - Removing the status bar completely**

To hide the status bar completely, add this on your onCreate method:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

You can read more on this at [Hiding the status bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status)

Result:

[image]

**4 - Removing the navigation Bar**

You can find a solution to this at the Android Developer site [Hiding the navigation bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation)

Basically just add this to your onCreate:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but there is any way to completely hide de navigation bar?

Comment: The navigation bar is hidden when I enter into the screen but when I touch any part of it, navbar appears again.

Comment: Hi arkandas I think you wrote almost all the options xD, but again Is it possible to keep the status and hide the navbar? with your second option navbar is hidden until I touch the screen. Anyway thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not understanding exactly what you want to achieve. Could you maybe upload a picture reflecting the end result you hope to get?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
private void setTransparentStatusBar(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } else {
        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes my nav bar translucent but the status bar is hidden anyway

Comment: This method doesn't hide the status bar, please remove the part in your code that does. I believe it's this one: `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN`