# How to make StatusBar transparent?

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar

Does anyone know a way to make Android Status Bar transparent with React Native?

NOT TRANSLUCENT, Transparent.

I am using react-navigation too.

Comment: try using `<StatusBar translucent={true} backgroundColor={'transparent'} />`

Comment: It becomes translucent and transparent. Meaning that the background gets under the Status bar. What I really need is that the status bar continues to exist (translucent="false") but with backgroundColor={'transparent'} it becomes a greyish color

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/12

Comment: I reviewed it tried most of examples there but no luck yet...

Comment: Make it translucent and add a padding top so that the status bar does in a way continue to exist

Answer (score 109):

Just use it like this:
Tested with: "react-native": "0.60.4" and "0.61.5"

```
<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
```

Comment: I've tried this and it working fine in iOS but in android not (`StatusBar._updatePropsStack`: Color transparant parsed to null or undefined)

Comment: transparant or transparent?

Comment: as per react native docs, https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#translucent-android, translucent defaults to false, so you need to set as `translucent={true}`

Comment: As per React JSX [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true) setting `<StatusBar translucent />` or `<StatusBar translucent={true} />` is the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

This is working for me on android

```
<StatusBar
   backgroundColor="transparent"
   translucent={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Unless you are using Statusbar as a component, try this method.

```
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      StatusBar.setBarStyle("dark-content");
      Platform.OS === 'android' && StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('transparent');
      StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
    }, []),
  );
```

Do not forget to give some `paddingTop` to the most outer `View`.

Answer (score 4):

`<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />` is the way to go, thx to @Felipe Rugai

However, 2 things to know:

1. If you are using `<Header />` component from `react-native-elements`, it already have `<StatusBar />` included, using its `statusBarProps` instead.
2. If you are using WIX react-native-navigation, they have a separate way to dealing with the status bar, refer to [this](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/style-statusBar/) and [this](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/style-options/). They said it is incompatible with React Native's , however, looks like they work well together for me.
3. Also android native code/config discussed in [another stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar) solution will override by `<StatusBar />` hence doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the status bar of the OS (the one you pull down to access wifi/bluetooth/settings etc), try adding this to you MainActivity.java:

```
private void hideNavigationBar() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

And you can call that^ function in this function from the same MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    hideNavigationBar();
}
```

However, if you're talking about the StatusBar of the app, try adding this to your App.js file

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
```

Comment: Both methods are useless. static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
} this is supposed to hide toolbar/topbar not status bar.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it using`StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(Colors.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: this not make any sence

Answer (score 0):

This solution can solve the issue if you're working with expo
in your package JSON /expo configuration: you can add a property to overwrite the default StatusBar for android

```
"androidStatusBar":{
    "translucent":false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should after

```
<StatusBar
   backgroundColor="transparent"
   translucent={true}
/>
```

re-run the app again

Answer (score -2):

Try this to make transparent statusbar in android

```
container: {
      flex:1,
      paddingTop: 20
    },
```

add display flex and paddingTop to your main `View` component

Comment: flex size & padding has nothing to do with status bar.

Answer (score -4):

In react native, if you are using expo you can go to the [app.json](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-statusbar/) file and add status bar color. After this background color of the status bar for the complete app will change.

```
"androidStatusBar": {
  "backgroundColor": "#105846"
},
```

Check the linked page.

Comment: this seems to me as not even HEX color at all