# Set Android status bar to completely transparent not work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.forms, android-actionbar, android-statusbar

I'm building my mobile application using Xamarin.Forms, and i currently have problem with setting the **status bar** in Android platform to be **completely transparent** (like this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar))

Because i am using xamarin.forms so i just want to handle this using Android's **styles.xml**

I have already read through this post([Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)) 
as well as some others similar posts and tried the same way but i still could not get it to work properly.

Here is my styles.xml :

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and here is my splash screen xml :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I was able to get my desired result with the status bar, however there still a problem with navigation bar.
Images here:
[image: Splash Screen]

[image: Screen]

As you can see in the image, the navigation bar take up the space of my app content.

Also when i change `android:windowTranslucentNavigation` to false, it produce a result like this image here, the position of the bars are correct but the color sucks [image: after]

Also i need to change the content color of the bars to darker color, not white like these images.

So my question is how can i get my status bar color to be completely transparent and my navigation bar to be translucent like in my first 2 images, and their position like in my last image, just by setting in styles.xml

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Might be kind of lazy but if no one else comes up with an answer you could just add padding on the bottom and top so it doesn't overlap

Comment: When you set status bar/navigation bar to translucent it will ignore color. So step 1, disable translucent navigation. `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>` Next, your window is responsible for drawing content behind status and navigation bars. I suggest you simplify your question to something like "how do I draw behind status bar and navigation bar" so people don't come in, suggesting step 1 and leaving (like I was about to).