# android status bar transparent in light theme

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to have a transparent statusBar in the light style like this

[image]

I tried this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        this.window.apply {
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.transparent)
        }
}
```

but I can't add `decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` for change  text color of statusBar because I add `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`

after that I used `setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/4519936) but my activity go under the back button like this

[image]

Comment: I think it is going behind the back button bar because of this `decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`. Do you want the back button bar or do youwant your app to be full screen always?

Comment: This is the navigation bar, not the status bar

Comment: NO, I want my app to stay above the back button @TheBat

Comment: I think if you remove the `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` it should  just work fine

Comment: Ok I know the second picture is a navigation bar but when I want to transparent my status bar, my navigation bar go on my app @Tim

Comment: It works fine but when I add ```decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR``` instead of ```decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN```  it doesn't work @TheBat

Comment: @mohsen did you check this https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/gesturenav#edge-to-edge. In case you are looking for edge to edge content!.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately go under the back button @Raghunandan

Comment: you need to set the flags properly and it should work

Comment: which OS version are you testing on, because, I just tried it on my app and works fine

Comment: Nexus 5x - Android 8.1.0 @TheBat

Comment: do you set this ```SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR``` @TheBat

Comment: No, I simply added the first code block that you have posted, now I added `setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` and now m y app also goes under the navigation bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this code

```
  val winParams = window?.getAttributes()
                winParams?.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                window?.setAttributes(winParams)
                window?.getDecorView()
                    ?.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

This for go back to the dark theme

```
val winParams = window?.attributes
            winParams?.flags = -2139029248
            window?.attributes = winParams
            window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = 0
            window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
```