# Set Color of Android StatusBar in NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript

I am working with Nativescript 8.5 and want to change the color of the StatusBar. I found already a [4 year old Stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62550687/set-status-bar-color-in-nativescript) which describes 3 solutions:

- add `androidStatusBarBackground` style to `Page` element
- add elements to `styles.xml` (android:statusBarColor, android:windowLightStatusBar, android:windowActionBarOverlay, android:windowTranslucentStatus)
- set it programmaticially via window.setStatusBarColor (`Application.android.startActivity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0);`)

But non of them changed anything. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that there two styles.xml in nativescript projects:

- `app/main/res/values/styles.xml`
- `app/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml`

I looked only in the first one, while the seconds one overwrote my `android:windowTranslucentStatus`. After removing `android:windowTranslucentStatus` form the second one all methods for settings the color of the statusBar worked.