# Can i Change Theme Color Bar browser to Gradient Color?

Tags: html, css

i want to change

```
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#4B53D8">
```

to

```
    <meta name="theme-color" content="linear-gradient(80deg, #ff3377, #3D55DF)">
```

**But this doesn't work, is there any other way?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
According to the spec and [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color), the value must be a [valid CSS color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

Comment: @Manesh Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This does not use `theme-color` and is specific to `iOS`. But a gradient background can be achieved with the following:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

Then in your `CSS` file, add the gradient to your `body` element:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(80deg, #ff3377, #3D55DF);
}
```

The only catch here, is that the text color in your App's status bar (I'm assuming this is for an app?) will be white and will not adjust to changes in your background color (if you decide you want to make this reactive).

For Android, I would then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/4087634).

Comment: Can you share some docs that states `black-transulent` is a valid value for this field?

From what I see, the only accepted type of value is [<color>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

Comment: Ahh, you are right. This is specific to iOS and is unrelated to `theme-color`. I have amended my answer above.