# Splash Activity in Android not setting as FULL SCREEN ACTIVITY - Samsung M51

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, statusbar, android-fullscreen

To make the Full-Screen Activity,
So far I have tried it as below :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

before setContentView() method in Activity.

Also Tried adding below lines :

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

But it not worked. Then, I have moved to manifest and Tried as below :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"

<activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
        android:name="SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and the stype I have tried above is as below :

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

And Yes, In my layout the Root tag is as below :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/bg_layout_screen">
```

means using  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Now, the issue is It's not visible as full-screen activity.
The issue screenshot is as below :

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]

But Still, the issue is as below Image.

First Image :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbJ2l.jpg

Second Image :
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTpgw.jpg

Black is while adding this line in manifest :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
```

Please guide. What might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: set attribute *android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode = shortEdges* in your style. this solution working me thnx.

Answer (score 1):

As per your first image you have to just change the color of your status bar to transperent.
To do it please refer below post

[Android Completely transparent Status Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar)

Hope this post helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onWindowFocusChanged()` and `View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();` then set **SystemUiVisibility**.

**Example:**

```
//set full screen
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    );
}
```

Comment: It's still black as in above image in my question ;)

Comment: make sure you written android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" in your manifest file.

Comment: Sholakiya Still same.