# Android 12 Navigation bar disappearing

Tags: android, navigation, resize

When pulling down the notifications, the gesture navigation bar on the bottom slides down, some apps like the PlayStore handle this well, while my app (and others like WA) is resizing, what is this about? Do I have to recompile with newer AndroidX version or do something in the manifest?

Couldn't find anything on this

[image]

(Take a close look at the bottom here ⬆️

Comment: When you create an empty activity app from the Android studio templates, do you have the same?

Comment: Didn't test, this also occurs on apps like WA and others like Ultimate Guitar

Comment: Not sure what device or Android variant you're using, but the navigation bar doesn't disappear on the official Android 12 emulator image. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2qa3UQU

Comment: Using Pixel 4a 5G with the stable channel - it is a bit buggy though, so maybe this will be fixed eventually, but not sure if this is a bug or a intended change of behavior, however, didn't find anything on this....

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  I could not reproduce the issue on the official Android 31 emulator image.

Secondly, it appears that the Google Play app layouts fit the system window and use translucent system bars. Since your app doesn't implement such behaviour, the app layout needs resizing when the navigation bar re-appears. On the other hand, the Play Store layouts don't need resizing because the navigation bar will overlay on top of it. You can implement a translucent navigation bar using the instructions provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/2410641).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, and report back.

Comment: After a few updates from Google, this no longer happens, so i believe this to be a bug in earlier Android 12 versions.