# Is there a way to change android status bar to transparent base on view pager content image?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2, android-statusbar

I have a viewpager2 in my app and I wanna use edge to edge status bar(as in second image) base on each viewpager page.
Is it possible?
*First image is what I've implemented it has white status bar.
App architecture is single activity with navigation.

[image: this is what I got in app]

[image: this is what our designer wants]

Comment: Maybe you can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar

Comment: Thank you I'll check it.