# Unable to make the Status Bar transparent in SDK AP1 21: Android 5.0 (lollipop)

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface, statusbar

Want to make the status bar transparent but it is turning black instead of being transparent. What's the matter ? Have used all the methods but yet it's not changing.I have changed the parent theme from MaterialComponents to App Compat , is it becoz of that ?

[image]

This is my themes.xml file.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.QuizApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/font10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="heading_name" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/font1</item>
        <item name="textFillColor">#2B0031</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/purple_gray</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/purple_gray</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.QuizApp.NoActionBarAndStatusBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/font10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="progressBarBlue" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">#4568dc</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.QuizApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.QuizApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

This is the activity_main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/screen_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <TextView
        style="@style/heading_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#450750"
        android:shadowDx="1.5"
        android:shadowDy="1.5"
        android:shadowRadius="1.6"
        android:text="Quiz App !"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHighlight="#8F22A1"
        android:textColorHint="#7F1491"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="50dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="100dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font3"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Welcome ! "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please Enter Your Name "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
            
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    tools:text="Nandini"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:shadowColor="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_gray"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/purple_gray"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_gray"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Start Quiz"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:elevation="100dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

This is MainActivity.kt file.

```
package com.nandini.android.quizapp


import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn_start : Button =findViewById(R.id.btn_start)
        val et_name : EditText=findViewById(R.id.et_name)
        btn_start.setOnClickListener {
            if(et_name.text.isEmpty())
            {
                et_name.setError("")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                val intent = Intent(this,QuizQuestionActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.USER_NAME,et_name.text.toString())
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Go through the link in the bottom you will get your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311078/android-completely-transparent-status-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these two lines in your main theme :

```
 <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
 <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

And you can use `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` as your main theme without any problems.