# How to show content below transparent status bar in Kitkat

Tags: android, layout, transparent

I am currently running Kitkat (4.4.2) in my phone and I installed an app.

In this app, the status bar is transparent and showing the content of the app below it.
Please see the images.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR136.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBk2r.jpg)

How should I do it in my program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keyword for searching is: "Android transparent status bar". First hit: http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx I will now vote to close as this is not a on-topic question for SO. Please read the [FAQ] for more details about how to ask what kind of questions.

Comment: Thanks WarrenFaith but the status bar shown in the blog u referred shows the bar with some dark shade. How to deal with that?

Comment: You should start searching! Two clicks to find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865621/transparent-status-bar-before-4-4-kitkat See the right lower list titled: "Related" You can find good related questions and answers there!

Comment: Thankx a lot :) WarrenFaith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WarrenFaith suggested[,http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx) contains the detailed answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to tint status bar color in kitkat.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Following is code for MainActivity.java

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
             w.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
             SystemBarTintManager systemBarTintManager = new         SystemBarTintManager(this);
            systemBarTintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            systemBarTintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(Color.parseColor("#689F38"));

    }
```